# Do I need any knowledge of Objective C to port a game to iOS using Unity3D?

Tags: android, unity, ios, porting

I have no experience with Objective-C and I know iOS simply as a user of iphone and ipad devices.

Now, I know that Unity3D can port my game to iOS without needing to know Objective C (that's what their docs say). But is it as simple as that? Click to compile, then use distribution profile and upload binaries to iTunes - as simple as that?

I need to know if should I start this process and publish my game this way. I am afraid that I may come across platform-dependent things (like when I code in cocoa-2dx using C++ and I come across hardware specific things).

If anyone has such experience, I would appreciate they share it with me.

Comment: Unity will not compile to a native application for iOS or Android. Instead, it runs on the Mono framework (Monodroid and whatever the one for iOS is). So, from your end, no objective-c is involved. The only thing here is to have a device on which you can physically test.

Comment: So, you're not trying it yet because you don't want to pay for it?

Comment: Right. I am also worried if anyone faced any problems which appeared later. On cocos-2dx which is also multiplatform, some hardware features on Android I have to code from scratch. Such feature on iOS, I am unable to code thus unable to port my app to iOS. I was wondering if anyone faces such problems with unity port to iOS.

Comment: First, you'd probably have MUCH better luck asking this over at [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com). Second, if you want to develop for iOS successfully, you will need to **test on a physical device**...which requires an iOS license for Unity.

Comment: @XGundam05 Thanks. I know about unity3d forum but I thought this one is maybe less partial :). I am aware about the license and about testing on a real device. That's clear to me. I am only trying to figure out did anyone got problems (such as with mic or gps or bluetooth) which was impossible to fix without writing an objective-c piece of code?

Comment: @XGundam05 while Unity has their own Q & A, the quality there is awful, the software it runs on is awful, and everything there is just.. awful.

Comment: @XGundam05: Unity runs in an in-house modified version of Mono, targeting iOS and Android. This is completely different from MonoDroid, which is the previous name of a product by a company called Xamarin (its current name is "Xamarin Android"). It's important to remember this distinction.

Comment: @PandaPajama Didn't realize that. I had assumed it was so as the licensing fee for the 'Basic' iOS and Android was the same as that for Monodroid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unity compiles your app into a bunch of assembly code with a thin Objective-C layer around it for OS calls and such.  Assuming you're not doing any plugin work (e.g. needing to call OS level features for things) you can publish your game without any working knowledge of Objective C.  Even if you do need OS level features, there's usually a plugin available that abstracts most of that stuff away for you.

However in my experience getting an the provisioning profile information set up and actually working is probably going to take you longer than learning Objective C anyway.  It's usually a pain to get everything set up properly.